# How do I spawn in weapons or items?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls

Is there a way in *Dark Souls 1*, *Dark Souls 2*, or *Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the First Sin* to spawn in weapons or items? I wanted to experiment with weapons that I didn't use on my first playthrough or get some practice on.

Comment: Not without risking a ban I suspect, assuming you're talking about the Steam versions.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Yes, but can't you launch the game offline of Steam and be fine?

Comment: What do you mean by spawning weapons? your using a cheat or a command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a tool called "Cheat Engine" that can be used to allow console commands, to spawn items, change quantities, transmute and do all sorts of wonderful things, so it should be able to suit your needs.

(I couldn't find a direct link to the Cheat Engine download, but if anyone does, feel free to add it.)

Comment: Cheat engine isn't a tool to enable console or commands. Cheat Engine is a tool that scans the ram memory for values you're looking for. You can for example look for a specific number of gold, let's say 100. If you scan for this Value you'll get a lot of memory areas where the 100 can be found and here's the trick of cheat engine, because you can search for changed values. If you found 10 memory entrys with a 100 you can change the value ingame (buy a poition for 10) so you have ingame 90. Search for this in cheat engine and it will look for a value that changed from 100 to 90 and so on.

Comment: Cheat engine also has a small Tutorial that is realy helpfull, but be carefull cause Cheat engine is a verry verry powerfull tool wich can cause problems. Direktly changing Memmory entries can kill every Programm routine. So be carefull what you do.